# img.onload not firing when src exists on localhost

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a custom image(file) uploader that successfully uploads and previews the images within the image uploader itself.

I am not trying to obtain the width/height of the said uploaded image such that if it exceeds a certain size I compress it to a desirable size.

My issue is that after created a new Image and then waiting for it to load, the onload function does not trigger, but rather the onerror function triggers.

[image: The file data being uploaded]

```
console.log(file) //above
let img = new Image()
img.onload = () => console.log('loaded') //does not trigger
img.onerror = () => console.log('error') //triggers
img.complete //returns true
img.src = file.name 
console.log(img.src) //http://localhost:3000/maxresdefault.png
```

It's probably something stupid that I can't see, but what could the cause that img.complete returns true and img.onerror triggers at the same time?

Comment: If `onerror` triggers, there should be an error in the console.

Comment: You're not loading the image from the local file, you're loading it from the server. Did you upload it to the root directory of the webserver?

Comment: It can't be in the root directory as this can be an unknown file. The whole point is to allow any user to upload their image, which can never be in the root directory. Unless I misunderstood your question. If what I am doing is incorrect, what would be a correct way of doing it?

Comment: You need to use `img.src = "/path/to/directory/" + file.name`, where `/path/to/directory/` is the appropriate URL.

Comment: I did window.location.pathname + file.name, still the same problem

Comment: That can't be right. That will create a URL ending with `/pagename.htmlmaxresdefault.png`. You need to get the directory where the images are stored.

Comment: Solved this by using    URL.createObjectURL(file)